# Проблема с префиксами при соединении таблиц

Tags: sql, таблицы, inner-join

У меня есть запрос, в котором используются префиксы.

```
SELECT    Код_почтового_отделения, Код_отдела
FROM      Графики_работы z1
where not exists (Select * from  Графики_работы z2 where 


      (Время_начала_перерыва BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '14:00:00' OR Время_окончания_перерыва 
       BETWEEN'12:00:00' AND '14:00:00')

       and z1.Код_почтового_отделения=z2.Код_почтового_отделения and z1.Код_отдела=z2.Код_отдела)
```

Из него я сделал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT        
              Почтовые_отделения.Код_почтового_отделения, 
              Индекс, 
              Код_отдела, 
              Время_начала_перерыва, 
              Время_окончания_перерыва

FROM           Графики_работы z1 INNER JOIN
                         Почтовые_отделения ON Графики_работы z1.Код_почтового_отделения and Графики_работы z1.Код_почтового_отделения = Почтовые_отделения.Код_почтового_отделения

WHERE    not exists (Select * from  Графики_работы z2 where 


         (Время_начала_перерыва BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '14:00:00' OR Время_окончания_перерыва BETWEEN'12:00:00' AND '14:00:00')
          and z1.Время_окончания_перерыва=z2.Код_почтового_отделения and z1.Код_отдела=z2.Код_отдела)
```

Но мне выдаёт ошибку: Рядом с "z1" в контексте, где ожидается условие, указано выражение типа, отличного от логического.
Помогите правильно прописать INNER JOIN во втором запросе.

Comment: Ошибка здесь: ON Графики_работы z1.Код_почтового_отделения
 и далее

Comment: Это я знаю. Как это написать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно написали [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). После слова `ON`, SQL ожидает увидеть условие, по которому будут объединены таблицы, но у вас используется `ON Графики_работы z1.Код_почтового_отделения and` что не является валидным.
Должно быть, что-то похожее на это:

```
FROM Графики_работы z1 
INNER JOIN Почтовые_отделения z2 ON z1.Код_почтового_отделения = z2.Код_почтового_отделения
```